# Is there a way to use a config object instead of database_url in prisma?

Tags: node.js, sql-server, nestjs, prisma

I am working on a project with nestJS and SQL Server. I want to use prisma as orm, however, for some reason my database_url is not working (the same url works on datagrip) when i try prisma db pull.
It always returns me the TLS connection error.

When I try to do the connection on another basic node project with config object it works just fine, I just need to set encrypt=false. I have done that on database_url for prisma, but it keeps returning the TLS connection error. I have also tried to set trustServerCertificate=true and still the same problem.
So, is there a way to work prisma with config object instead of database_url, in a way that I still can do the prisma db pull?
Thanks